# Golang return struct pointer with New() instead of creating one directly

Tags: pointers, go, struct, new-operator, dereference

I'm reading this [repo](https://github.com/go-resty/resty) unittest code and the `Client` struct is created in a way that I never seen before.

```
type Client struct {
    // client stuff
}

// In client_test.go
// Creating default client for testing
c := dc()

// In resty_test.go
func dc() *Client {
    DefaultClient = New()
    DefaultClient.SetLogger(ioutil.Discard)
    return DefaultClient
}
```

My question is that what is the purpose of returning `New()`?
Does the code below behave similarly as the `New()` style? Why should choose one over another?

```
func dc() *Client {
    DefaultClient := Client{}
    return &DefaultClient
}
```

Comment: The [New() function](https://github.com/go-resty/resty/blob/63ac6744519b3b3e976256d87d7b097c3a2c8dbc/default.go#L25-L28) function is not the built-in [new()](https://godoc.org/builtin#new) function.  The New() function does more than `Client{}`.  I assume that that the extra initialization in New() is required for the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `New()` function is a constructor function for the `Client`:

https://github.com/go-resty/resty/blob/63ac6744519b3b3e976256d87d7b097c3a2c8dbc/default.go#L25

Using a constructor function allows for structs to be constructed with default values set instead of using the zero values for all the internal fields like doing `Client{}` would do.  For instance, the maximum body size is set to `math.MaxInt32` not 0 in this case.